# Windows Phone control tv over wifi

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, mobile-application, television

I'd like to create a Windows Phone 8.1 app to connect to a TV and have basic controls (change channels, turn on/off).

I know It's hard to have an universal remote for every TV, but I'm just testing so It could work to a specific model/maker.

My first guess is to connect to a smart tv over wifi connection, but I can't find any site to describe how to do this or how do I start researching. I only got links to apps already made, but not on how to build it.

Anyone knows how this connection works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont think this is really related to Windows phone specific. but here is what you can do:

find out what kind of API the TV has. it's probably some Rest or SOAP based webservice you can call. if there are existing apps (maybe for other platforms) you can use Fiddler to check the network traffic from these apps to the TV if you set your pc as "man in the middle" with fiddler.

as soon as you have what you need look into HttpClient examples on how to send these requests toward your TV.

fiddler :http://www.telerik.com/fiddler
HttpClient: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298639